# If I have lots of strings with a similar prefix, is there a reason to create a substring out of that prefix?

Tags: c++, string

I wasn't exactly sure how to formulate this question.
I think it is easier to show with an example.

Say I have the following strings in my code: 
`std::string str1 = "Wild_Dog";` 
`std::string str2 = "Wild_Cat";` 
`std::string str3 = "Wild_Human";` 
`std::string str4 = "Wild_Goblin";` 
`std::string str5 = "Wild_Dragon";`

Is there any reason other than coding style to instead write the code like this?

`std::string prefix = "Wild_";` 
`std::string str1 = prefix + "Dog";` 
`std::string str2 = prefix + "Cat";` 
`std::string str3 = prefix + "Human";` 
`std::string str4 = prefix + "Goblin";` 
`std::string str5 = prefix + "Dragon";`

(Note: there is no other variable instead of wild_***, so it will always be the same prefix)

Comment: It depends a bit on what you want to do with the strings. It won't save you any memory. It even could be a bit slower since you create a temporary (but maybe the compiler optimizes that). Personally I think coding style alone is a good enough reason to do it that way^^

Comment: there are arguments for either options: DRY (dont repeat `"Wild"`. When you want to change it to `"Tamed"` you want to change it in one place only) vs performance (dont create unnecessary temporary strings). Without more context it is impossible to decide. In general write code for readability, not to save memory or a couple of cpu cycles.

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but maybe it would be a bit better to make `prefix` a `constexpr const char*` (We can't create `constexpr std::string`). So the compiler will probably just create your first code above and you will nonetheless DRY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I overengineered that a bit: https://godbolt.org/z/x4wf5r. This should have both the best possible performance and also has the prefix only specified once.